# iText extract "?" instead of "fi"

Tags: parsing, pdf, itext

I use iText 5.3.3

I try to extract text from pdf file.

I use something like that:

```
    File f (....)

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);

    r = new PdfReader(fis);

    String s=PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(r, 1);
    System.out.print(s);
```

I get this:

"(...)Singapore Airlines to the crisis caused by the ?rst fatal crash in the history(...)"

for text:

"(...)Singapore Airlines to the crisis caused by the first fatal crash in the history(...)"

or:
"(...)national carriers and ?nal conclusions suggest the need for(...)"

for text:
"(...)national carriers and final conclusions suggest the need for(...)"

as you see, i get "?" insted of "fi".

Comment: As HRN pointed out in his answer, there are ligature glyphs used for certain character combinations. If there is a proper mapping to Unicode for this glyph, it maps to the Unicode choose for that ligature, not for the separated characters. Most likely your console font does not know that character and, therefore, displays "?". If, on the other hand, there us no proper mapping to a Unicode character, text extraction routines are at a loss and also may include a "?" Character. For an analysis, please supply the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I changed default encoding for .txt files.

In Eclipse:
Window>>General>>Content Types>>Text
Default encoding: UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

"fi" can be a unicode character known as LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FI

More info on that character can be found here.

http://www.eki.ee/letter/chardata.cgi?ucode=FB01

This usually happens because of encoding issue or if the font used on the webpage where you displaying this text does not decode the font in which "fi" is rendered in the source.

Try to normalize your pdf reader string with UTF8 encoding and if the browser font does not know how to render it, you might want to check for unicode characters and parse out not needed characters like "fi".

One way to do this will be to write a regex that can parse out any unwanted unicode characters. Below is an example

```
 //Used this to get the unicode range below : http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl
                s = s.Replace(/[^\u0000-\u036F\u2000-\u2023\u2153-\u217E\u20A0-\u20B5]/g, "");
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Comment: I try to use that like:
s.replace("/[^\u0000-\u036F\u2000-\u2023\u2153-\u217E\u20A0-\u20B5]/g", "");

but do not help.

Comment: I don't think the original poster wants to throw away the ligatures. Instead he surely wants them converted to separate letters.